# react native external packages will take more memory in project

Tags: android, npm, react-native, reactive-programming, es6-module-loader

I need to add few packages which is already available on GitHub like tab layout and material icons etc,My question is,Is this will take more space on my project and as well as in my build? then another questions is when i use that packages files within my project it will also do same or is there any weight difference of these approach.Please someone clarify me

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

yes it will take more space on you project. But sometimes this extra space won't be a problem.

Here is a tool to check the cost of your modules inside your project:

https://github.com/siddharthkp/cost-of-modules

Comment: Thanks for the response.If i added in my project is this will increase app size?

Comment: If you add this module it will increase app size. But this tool is just to show your module costs. You can add, use it and then remove it.